# the configuration refers to the unknown class 'String'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

I am using Android Studio and the ProGuard Plugin.

When I build my release I get the following note:

```
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'String'
    Maybe you meant the fully qualified name 'java.lang.String'?
```

Here is my Gradle config:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-guava.pro'
```

Here is proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontnote org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver
-dontnote org.apache.http.conn.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.params.**
-dontnote android.net.http.**

-dontnote **ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
```

Here is proguard-guava.pro:

```
-keep class com.google.common.io.Resources {
    public static <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.common.collect.Lists {
    public static ** reverse(**);
}
-keep class com.google.common.base.Charsets {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class com.google.common.base.Joiner {
    public static Joiner on(String);
    public ** join(...);
}

-keep class com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$ReferenceEntry
-keep class com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$ReferenceEntry

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
```

**What does this means?**

Comment: Is it your ProGuard that is spitting this out?

Comment: Yes it comes from Proguard!

Comment: Then paste your prograurd file

Comment: Which file? Do you mean my config?

Comment: In your build.gradle you are defining which proguard file you are using. eg: `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`. Copy/paste the one you have in your directory.

Comment: @ChadBingham please see my edit. I posted the content there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `proguard-guava.pro` file, try changing this:

```
-keep class com.google.common.base.Joiner {
    public static Joiner on(String);
    public ** join(...);
}
```

to this:

```
-keep class com.google.common.base.Joiner {
    public static Joiner on(java.lang.String);
    public ** join(...);
}
```

notice the `java.lang.String` difference.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: By the way is this the correct way to use Guava rules for ProGuard?

Comment: Yeah it looks good to me. You could just put all of the content from that file in to your other one, to condense things. But it is not needed

Comment: Do you have an idea on this too: ``Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean calls 'Field.getType'``

Comment: No, sorry. I am not sure what is causing that.